# Tikz: How to make edges touch a symbol?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This simple code creates an intersection of 3 edges meeting at an $\otimes$ symbol:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0, 0)(A) {A};
  \node at (0, 2.0)(B) {B};
  \node at (2.0, 1.6)(C) {C};
  \node at (1.0, 1.2)(X) {$\otimes$};
  \draw[line width=2](A) -- (X);
  \draw[line width=2](B) -- (X);
  \draw[line width=2](C) -- (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I make the edges actually reach up to the $\otimes$ symbol or as close as possible, as if the symbol is sitting on the intersection?

It should look like this (excuse my drawing skills):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use "shorten" option with a negative value

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0, 0)(A) {A};
        \node at (0, 2.0)(B) {B};
        \node at (2.0, 1.6)(C) {C};
        \node at (1.0, 1.2)(X) {$\otimes$};
        \draw[line width=2,shorten >=-5pt](A) -- (X);
        \draw[line width=2,shorten >=-6pt](B) -- (X);
        \draw[line width=2,shorten >=-4pt](C) -- (X);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could give the node a specific shape instead of using an `\otimes` as its contents (if you zoom in closely, you will see that the lines touch the circle but only in the middle, leaving small gaps at the outer edges):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    cross/.append style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra{
                \draw (\tikzlastnode.north west) -- (\tikzlastnode.south east)
                      (\tikzlastnode.north east) -- (\tikzlastnode.south west);
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0, 0)(A) {A};
  \node at (0, 2.0)(B) {B};
  \node at (2.0, 1.6)(C) {C};
  \node[draw, circle, cross, inner sep=3pt] at (1.0, 1.2) (X) {};
  \draw[line width=2](A) -- (X);
  \draw[line width=2](B) -- (X);
  \draw[line width=2](C) -- (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This draws the symbol on top of the lines.  Note that `\otimes` (like every character) is itself a rectangle.   The negative inner sep was found by trial and error.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0, 0)(A) {A};
  \node at (0, 2.0)(B) {B};
  \node at (2.0, 1.6)(C) {C};
  \coordinate (X) at (1.0, 1.2);
  \draw[line width=2](A) -- (X);
  \draw[line width=2](B) -- (X);
  \draw[line width=2](C) -- (X);
  \node[circle, inner sep=-1.3pt, fill=white] at (X) {$\otimes$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]